# how to show the my current location in the Google Map?

Tags: android

I want to show my current location in google map. it should be coming dynamically i.e. longitute and latitude should be set dynamically.

Like if now I am in New Delhi , and if I start my android application,my current location should be shown in New Delhi and it should change if I travel to other cities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the current location 
[What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an/3145655#3145655)

and pass that value to google map api.