# Map application which show a current location

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to show the my current location in the Google Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202071/how-to-show-the-my-current-location-in-the-google-map)

I want to show my current location in google map. it should be coming dynamically i.e. longitute and latitude should be set dynamically.

Comment: A simple search is a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202071/how-to-show-the-my-current-location-in-the-google-map

Comment: thanks for sharing what you want, You are doing great then. All the best. :P Search on Google for tutorial.

Comment: you need to have a gps and if u using emulator it wont work..just tpye  API GPS + android in GOOGLE

Answer (score -1):

You need to follow below steps.

1) open browser type www.google.com

2) Search "*Map Appliction tutorial + Android*" and press search in it.

3) I found this [Map View Application](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview) as a top third  link, which is having complete tutorial(*To create map and overlay for locations*) from Developers site of Android

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: but it will display "Provider not found."

Comment: Rread it thoroughly , You need to add related permissions in manifest file.

Comment: Please help me : How to download source code for a apllication

Comment: Sorry, read the link provided, do whatever it tells.